# how to restrict update on a specific column of a table via trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, restriction

I have a teacher_table that contain of few column of data like teacher_name,teacher_age,teacher_phone and teacher_gender.

I want to create a trigger query that restrict user to update the teacher_gender column in my teacher_table. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: What database are you using?  Triggers are implemented in some procedural extension language but that procedural extension language is going to be different for every database engine.  The SQL Server trigger is going to be totally different than the Oracle trigger or the MySQL trigger or some other database's trigger.

Comment: I am using sql database.

Comment: SQL is a language, not a database.  Many databases have "SQL" in the name.  SQL Server, MySQL, and PostgreSQL for example.  Are you using one of these?  Or something else?

Comment: SQL server.........

Comment: OK.  That's helpful.  What is the primary key of the `teacher` table?  Is there a `teacher_id`?  Or is `teacher_name` supposed to be the key?

Comment: Teacher_ID is the PK. Then i do not what to allow user to able to update Teacher_gender. and i tried the solution form karliwson. And it does not accept before update on trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
create trigger teacher_gender_check_update
before update on teacher_table
for each row
begin
    if (old.teacher_gender IS NOT NULL) then
        SIGNAL 'Teacher gender already set'
    end if ;
end;
```